# Simple google maps call not working js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps

I'm trying to create a simple google maps, but this simple setup does not seem to work, anyone can tell me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

HTML

```
<script defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBy2rXc1YewdnqhPaaEd7H0I4DTV_pc7fo&">

</script>

<div id="map"> </div>
```

JS

```
    function initMap() {
    console.log('test');
    var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
}
```

Document Ready Function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initMap();
});
```

Comment: `does not work` What does that mean? - What doesn't work? What are you expecting? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Expected to let the map work and it did not show any errors! got to fix it to put the document ready above the init somehow. not sure why tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your `callback` parameter not given in <script>.
- div without width & height.
- if you doesn't to use callback parameter,the <script> not need defer

```js
function initMap() {
    console.log('test');
    var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
}
```

```html
<script defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBy2rXc1YewdnqhPaaEd7H0I4DTV_pc7fo&callback=initMap">

</script>
<div id="map" style="width:300px;height:300px;"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add width and height to your div.

```
<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding &callback=initMap after you api in script call

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    initMap();
});

function initMap() {
    console.log('test');
    var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
}
```

```css
#map
{
width:500px;height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBy2rXc1YewdnqhPaaEd7H0I4DTV_pc7fo&">

</script>

<div id="map" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the code work. 
You need to specify the height and width of your div.

Either by using inline css

```
style="width:400px;height:400px;"
```

Or by using CSS

```
#map {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Test : https://jsfiddle.net/LmckLLjj/

Answer (score 0):

Please set height and width to you map div

Coz, by default div height and width is 0

PLease change your div like this

```
<div id="map" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
```

Or u can set css like this :

```
<style>
#map{
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
</style>
```